# Не работает скрипт подсчет даты

Tags: php, centos, datetime

Локально на девере (версия php 5.3.13) все хорошо работает на сервере centos 6.4, версия php v5.0.19 не работает. пустой экран. Даже ошибки не выводит.

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2012-05-25'); 
$date2 = new DateTime("now"); 
$interval = $date1->diff($date2); 
$diff_rab = $interval->format('%y лет %m месяцев %d дней');
```

Comment: DAteTime в этой версии не работает, по-моему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Даже ошибки не выводит.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

> php v5.0.19 не работает

http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php

> (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7)

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1); действительно помогло? вышли ошибки и предупреждения

Comment: временно поставил date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); до обновления php

Answer (score 3):

Проверяем [мануал](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

> (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7)

Класс был добавлен только в PHP 5.2.0. А метод [`diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) - вовсе в 5.3.0:

> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)

Что далеко не 5.0. Кстати, версии PHP 5.0.19 не существует, последняя версия этой ветки была 5.0.5. Поэтому уточните установленную версию PHP.

> пустой экран. Даже ошибки не выводит.

Это обычно говорит о том, что у вас выключен вывод ошибок, директивы `display_errors` и `error_reporting`. Поищите детали ошибки в логе ошибок веб-сервера.